# Suggestions for data structure for keyword search

Tags: java, lucene, keyword

I need to put together a data structure that will efficiently provide keyword search facilities.

My metrics are:

1. Circa 500,000 products.
2. Circa 20+ keywords per product (a guess).
3. Products are identified by an ID of about 10 digits but may be any ASCII codes going forward.

I would like to try to fit the data structure in memory if possible. I will be on a server so I can assume some significant memory availability.

Speed is important. Using `LIKE` database queries will not be an acceptable solution.

Any ideas for a data structure?

My thoughts:

**TrieMap**

Very efficient for the keywords but there would need to be a list of product IDs hanging off any leaf so seriously memory hungry. Any ideas that could help with that?

**Compression**

Various compression schemes come to mind but none jump out as of significant value.

Has anyone else put something like this together? Could you share your experiences?

The data may change but not often. It would be reasonable to rebuild the structure on a daily basis to accommodate changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about using [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) either in memory or as a file system index?

It is quite fast and has lots of room for further requirements that might arise in the future.

Comment: Was just looking into how you do this with lucene but it looks like a Google search was the best thing to do - http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/

Comment: Thanks!! It took me half a day to build an index that worked and it looks like it will take me little more than that to completely replace an existing hideous search mechanism with Lucene. A truly exceptional package - so long as it continues to be as stable as it looks to be at first glance.

Comment: BTW - There's an excellent Lucene tutorial doc [here](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe-book/lucene-3-tutorial-0.5.pdf).